# No adapters available for bluetooth Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth

> **Note**: This issue arose as a result of a recent update to the mediatek drivers. If you're having a similar issue with Mediatek devices, the answer(s) below may be of assistance.

I am using `kubuntu 21.10`. My Wi-Fi is working fine. But I am not able to use Bluetooth.
I am using dual boot (Linux + Window). I can use Bluetooth in window. Please see my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OanI.png) of Kubuntu.

Note : I have already disabled my secured boot from BIOS options.

**Edit 1** :

1. Output of `sudo lshw` is given in my [codepen link](https://codepen.io/abhishekml/pen/poWKREQ).
2. Output of `sudo dmesg` is given in my [codepen link](https://codepen.io/abhishekml/pen/PoJaWpO).
3. Output of `sudo hcitool dev` => `Devices:`
   (Hence output of sudo hcitool dev is empty).
4. Output of `journalctl -xb | grep blue` is given below -

```
░░ Subject: A start job for unit bluetooth.service has begun execution
░░ A start job for unit bluetooth.service has begun execution.
Jan 05 21:54:27 abhishek-kamal-TUF bluetoothd[667]: Bluetooth daemon 5.60
░░ Subject: A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished successfully
░░ A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished successfully.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit bluetooth.target has finished successfully
░░ A start job for unit bluetooth.target has finished successfully.
Jan 05 21:54:27 abhishek-kamal-TUF bluetoothd[667]: Starting SDP server
Jan 05 21:54:27 abhishek-kamal-TUF bluetoothd[667]: Bluetooth management interface 1.20 initialized
Jan 05 21:54:27 abhishek-kamal-TUF NetworkManager[670]: <info>  [1641399867.8900] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.32.12/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Jan 05 21:54:29 abhishek-kamal-TUF systemd-xdg-autostart-generator[1070]: Exec binary 'blueman-applet' does not exist: No such file or directory
Jan 05 21:54:29 abhishek-kamal-TUF systemd-xdg-autostart-generator[1070]: Not generating service for XDG autostart app-blueman@autostart.service, error parsing Exec= line: No such file or directory
Jan 05 21:54:44 abhishek-kamal-TUF systemd-xdg-autostart-generator[1171]: Exec binary 'blueman-applet' does not exist: No such file or directory
Jan 05 21:54:44 abhishek-kamal-TUF systemd-xdg-autostart-generator[1171]: Not generating service for XDG autostart app-blueman@autostart.service, error parsing Exec= line: No such file or directory
Jan 05 21:54:45 abhishek-kamal-TUF systemd-xdg-autostart-generator[1307]: Exec binary 'blueman-applet' does not exist: No such file or directory
Jan 05 21:54:45 abhishek-kamal-TUF systemd-xdg-autostart-generator[1307]: Not generating service for XDG autostart app-blueman@autostart.service, error parsing Exec= line: No such file or directory
Jan 05 21:54:46 abhishek-kamal-TUF dbus-daemon[1178]: [session uid=1000 pid=1178] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez.obex' unit='dbus-org.bluez.obex.service' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=1405 comm="/usr/bin/kded5 " label="unconfined")
Jan 05 21:54:46 abhishek-kamal-TUF dbus-daemon[1178]: [session uid=1000 pid=1178] Successfully activated service 'org.bluez.obex'
```

5. Output of `sudo lsusb` is given below -

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0781:558a SanDisk Corp. Ultra
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 322e:202c Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0461:4d81 Primax Electronics, Ltd Dell N889 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132905/discussion-on-question-by-abhishek-kamal-no-adapters-available-for-bluetooth-kub).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the latest stable kernel which supports your device.

1. Install the bash script which automatically checks and install the latest kernel:

   ```
   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh
   sudo install ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh /usr/local/bin/
   ```
2. Run the bash script:

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -c
   ```
3. Install the latest stable kernel:

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -i
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Y</kbd> to accept the installation.
5. Reboot to boot into the latest kernel:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

You can also install the drivers using the deb files (better and stable):

1. Update the repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Download the deb files:

   ```
    wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.16.0-051600-generic_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_amd64.deb
    wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16/amd64/linux-modules-5.16.0-051600-generic_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Make the files executables:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x *.deb
   ```
4. Install the files:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```
5. Satisfy the dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt -f install
   ```
6. Install the headers for the kernel (Optional)

   ```
   sudo apt install linux-headers-generic
   ```
7. Reboot to boot into the newer kernel:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: It is now working properly in my side. Thanks for the continuous help. A big thank-you ! Love you man (I hope you are man).

Comment: @Abhishekkamal I'm happy to help :-D

Comment: @Abhishekkamal You were correct! I've actually added repetitive steps. Now I've removed them. Thanks :)